# Fatal Error with Omnipay + Mollie

Tags: omnipay, mollie

I'm trying to integrate payments via mollie.com using the extension "Omnipay multiprocessor support" (version 1.9).

I created a contribution page to test it, and I am using a test API key from Mollie.

When I test-drive my contribution page I am redirected to the site of Mollie, where I can select a payment method. So far so good, but when I am redirected back to my civicrm site, I get a fatal error:

Omnipay\Common\Exception\InvalidRequestException: "The transactionReference parameter is required"

Is it because I am using the test API key? Or is there another (configuration) issue?

The stack trace shows:

```
#0 sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/vendor/omnipay/common/src/Omnipay/Common/Message/AbstractRequest.php(610): Omnipay\Mollie\Message\CompletePurchaseRequest->getData()
#1 sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/CRM/Core/Payment/OmnipayMultiProcessor.php(816): Omnipay\Common\Message\AbstractRequest->send()
#2 sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/CRM/Core/Payment/OmnipayMultiProcessor.php(792): CRM_Core_Payment_OmnipayMultiProcessor->processPaymentNotification((Array:2))
#3 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment.php(1242): CRM_Core_Payment_OmnipayMultiProcessor->handlePaymentNotification()
#4 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment.php(1147): CRM_Core_Payment::handlePaymentMethod("PaymentNotification", (Array:3))
#5 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Payment::handleIPN()
#6 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): call_user_func((Array:2))
#7 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#8 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#9 sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#10 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("payment", "ipn", "2")
#11 includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#12 index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#13 {main}
```

Thanks!

Comment: i see some other discussions re Mollie at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor - if you haven't asked there alread you may want to

Comment: yup, specifically latest comments on [eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor#6](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/issues/6) mention this issue - if not already resolved, you may be able to help solve the issue just by debugging / giving more information there - Eileen is asking for confirmation of eg CiviCRM version (other details like CMS and PHP version may help, if you can update your question or post to that thread)

Comment: Version 2.1 of the nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocess extension - which was released today - solves this issue. Many thanks to Eileen!